# Multiple Scope value in Binding (Specflow)

Tags: scope, automated-tests, specflow, feature-selection, feature-file

I have a method which runs Before a feature like so,

```
[BeforeFeature, Scope(Feature = "Feature1"]
Method()
{
}
```

I want the same method to be ran for another feature file that i've wiritten i.e. Feature2

How do i combine this "Feature2" in the scope Binding?

I tried this

```
[BeforeFeature, Scope(Feature = "Feature1"]
[Scope(Feature="Feature2")]
```

but didn't work. The method only runs for Feature1 and not for Feature2

Comment: Solution here (DavideGalifi comment):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180578/specflow-and-reusing-steps-from-another-feature/41891994#41891994

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [scoping rules](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Scoped-bindings) multiple `Scope` bindings will be OR'd so I would expect the second example to work. Are you sure that you are spelling the feature name correctly?

I'll try and get an example worked up to verify this behaviour.

Comment: Figured it out. The SPELLING was wrong. Consumed half of my day. Thanks for that anyways!

Comment: @AutomateFr33k That was my suggestion 12 hours ago :). Sorry you lost half your day though...